# How to make a wordpress sidebar conditional?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, categories, sidebar

I'm working on a Wordpress site that uses the Reason theme from Themeforest. I have been
able to work out all issues except for two, one of which is the basis for this question.

The theme comes with a sidebar, but I want to disable it unless the user is on one of two
category pages OR on a post in one of those two categories.

Here is the code from page.php that calls the sidebar:

```
<div class="four columns sidebar">          
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'default-widget-area' ); ?>  
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some functions that can help you with that:

1. [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) should be used when the user is on a post of the category (single.php)
2. [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) should be used when the user is on a category page (category.php)

From [WordPres Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags),

```
in_category( array( 1,2,3 ) ) 
    Returns true if the current post is in either category 1, 2, or 3.
```

Comment: So would this be the proper code:

        <?php if(in_category( array( 14,15 ) )); ?>
  <div class="four columns sidebar">   
   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'default-widget-area' ); ?> 
  </div>
  <!-- /SIDEBAR -->
        <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Maybe you should add a `is_category()` too in case the user is on a category page (not on a post)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout WooSidebars - http://wordpress.org/plugins/woosidebars/

This is a great plugin that has all kinds of logic that should fit your use case. You can create multiple widget areas in sidebars a on pages, page templates, and so on.